# How can I rotate dygraph x labels

Tags: r, dygraphs

Using [dygraphs](https://rstudio.github.io/dygraphs/index.html) I want to be able to rotate x-axis labels. The [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dygraphs/dygraphs.pdf) does not tell about it.

On the example bellow I'd like the dates to be rotated to appear vertically

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you could try that

first save this css (as dygraph.css) file in your working directory. You can play with the css file, but you will have to resize your plot somehow because we hardly see the x axis label. You can increase the font size, but half of your label is cut-off.

```
.dygraph-title {
  color: navy;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.dygraph-axis-label-x {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    float: right;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
      font-size: 5px;
}
img.resize{
    width:540px; /* you can use % */
    height: 250;
}
graph_div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  top: 140px;
  bottom: 300px;
}
```

and then using you example

```
lungDeaths <- cbind(ldeaths, mdeaths, fdeaths)
dygraph(lungDeaths, main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>%
  dyOptions(colors = RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Set2")) %>% dyCSS("dygraph.css")
```

which give:
[image]

Comment: tx I was hoping I could fix that in R instead of going to the CSS itself. Problem with your solution is that any selector bar bellow will get over the labels. Looks like dygraphs isn't quite yet "featured" enough. I filled an FR on the github project. I'll go back to plotly in the meantime

Comment: I am not sure but you might have the same problem with plotly

Comment: and next time, maybe you should specify in your question if there is something you don't want.

Comment: No it's handled. Too bad dygraphs downsample fairly efficiently compared to plotly

Comment: Still +'ed the answer